# How to add flatpages to django suit menu

Tags: django, django-flatpages

How do I add flatpages app to django suit menu? I have tried the following configurations.

from settings.py

```
'MENU': (
    {'app': 'dongledb', 'label': 'Dongles', 'icon': 'icon-fire'},
    {'app': 'projapp', 'label': 'Manage', 'icon': 'icon-edit'},
    {'app': 'ruleskb', 'label': 'Rulesets', 'icon': 'icon-road'},
    {'app': 'userprofile', 'label': 'User Profile', 'icon': 'icon-user'},
    {'app': 'report_builder', 'label': 'Report Builder', 'icon': 'icon-filter'},
    {'label': 'Executive Dashboard', 'icon': 'icon-filter', 'url': '/execdash/xls'},
    {'app': 'chronograph', 'label': 'Scheduled Jobs', 'icon': 'icon-time'},
    {'app': 'currencies', 'label': 'Currencies', 'icon': 'icon-fire'},
    {'app': 'cities_light', 'label': 'Country/Region/Cities', 'icon': 'icon-plane'},
    {'app': 'aws_manager', 'label': 'AWS Cloud', 'icon': 'icon-fire'},
    'sites',
    'flatpages',

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'suit',
    'suit_ckeditor',
    # enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
```

from admin.py

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

# We have to unregister the normal admin, and then reregister ours
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage)
```

Nothing is showing on the menu.

Answer (score -1):

```
{'app': 'flatpages', 'label': 'Pages'},
```